# Embedable Flair with particular tag reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Follow up from my previous question, about [Reputation per Tag basis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295006/reputation-on-tag-instead-of-user).
I believed it would be better to have a Flair that show the reputation of a person based on a particular tag.

I'm not an employer, but I guess employer would be interested in looking at a user reputation on particular skill rather than the entire reputation.

Should we have this feature?